# Giving access to the S3 bucket only for the keycloak user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am running keycloak in the ecs cluster. I need to give access to the s3 bucket when a user gets registered in the keycloak. Is there any way how we can do it?